# Require JS : Undefine a file on click

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using require to load a file (template.view.js) on a page, now I want to undefine the file(template.view.js) on click of a button on my page.

I am looking for something like require.undef('templatekey').

Comment: Are you sure this is not a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you're looking for a solution to the wrong problem? Because this seems a very weird thing to do.

Comment: lemme elaborate further
I am using require js to load a modules(say a,b and c) to my backbone views, now on logout, the view on screen changes but the modules(say a,b and c) still stay. I want to make sure that these modules also unload when i hit the logout button.